# Commutative ring, commutative ring without zero divisors or field?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm in my first year of University and struggle with the following exercise in linear algebra.

I have to determine if the following sets are a commutative ring, a ring without zero dividers or a field.

$
\mathbb{Z}[ \sqrt{3} ] := \{ a+b\sqrt{3} | a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \} \subseteq \mathbb{R}
$

and
$
\mathbb{Q}[ \sqrt{3} ] := \{ a+b\sqrt{3} | a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \} \subseteq \mathbb{R}
$

I know that $\mathbb{(Q,+,\cdot)}$ is a field and am allowed to use that. Therefore I would just say, that $
\mathbb{Q}[ \sqrt{3} ] := \{ a+b\sqrt{3} | a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \} \subseteq \mathbb{R}
$ is a field because it only uses the operations $+$ and $\cdot$ and $a, b\in \mathbb{Q}$ and we know that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field.

For $\mathbb{Z}[ \sqrt{3} ] $ I would say that $\mathbb{Z}$ an abelian group:

1. In $\mathbb{Z}$ we can use $(a+b)+c=a+(b+c)$
2. in $\mathbb{Z}$ we can use  $a+b =b+a$
3. It is $0 \in \mathbb{Z}$, therefore $a+0 = 0+a = a$
4. There exists $-a \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a+(-a) = a-a= 0$.

We also can say, that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a monoid because

1. if $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $(a\cdot b)\cdot c = (a \cdot b) \cdot c$
2. there is $1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ therefore for $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $1 \cdot a = a$

And at last, we can say that $\mathbb{Z}$ is distributive.

I'm not exactly sure if this answer would suffice or if this is missing the goal of the exercise. Can someone help me?

Comment: A field has no zero divisors, so think about what that tells you about subsets of a field.  To be a field you need *all* nonzero numbers in it to have multiplicative inverse in it. Is that true for $\mathbf Q[\sqrt{3}]$?  For example, does $1/(7 + 2\sqrt{3})$ lie in $\mathbf Q[\sqrt{3}]$?  (Rationalize the denominator, and remember this is just *one example*.) What about for $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{3}]$?  An example that is *not* a field is $\mathbf Q[\pi] = \{a_0 + a_1\pi + \cdots  + a_n\pi^n : n \geq 0, a_i \in \mathbf Q\}$: $1/\pi$ is not a polynomial in $\pi$ with rational coefficients.

Comment: Thanks for your answe! Basically since $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational the multiplicative inverse of your example or any example with $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational, therefore doesn't exist in $\mathbb{Q}$. Just like your example with $Q[\pi]$ because we know that $\pi$ is irrational. Is that correct?

Comment: You missed my point: did you *try* to compute $1/(7+2\sqrt{3})$?  Rationalize the denominator and see what you get (simpler example: $1/\sqrt{3} = \sqrt{3}/3 = (1/3)\sqrt{3}$ is in $\mathbf Q[\sqrt{3}]$).  There is a *huge* difference between polynomials in $\pi$ with rational coefficients and polynomials in $\sqrt{3}$ with rational coefficients because $\sqrt{3}$ is a root of $x^2 - 3$, which is a (nonconstant) polynomial with rational coefficients.  The number $\pi$, in contrast, is transcendental.

Answer (score 1):

$x,y\in$ $\mathbb{Z}[ \sqrt{3} ] = \{ a+b\sqrt{3} | a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

$x=a+b\sqrt3$ , $y=c+d\sqrt3$

Let  $xy=0$ then $ac+(ad+bc)\sqrt3+3db=0$

we know that $ad+bc=0$ and $ac+3db=0$

$d(a-3b)=(a-b)c$

$bc^2=3db^2$

$b(c^2-3db)=0$

$b=0$ or $c^2=3db$

$b=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $a=0$ which means $x=0$

$c^2=3db$ $\Rightarrow$ $c^2+ac=0$

$c^2+ac=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $c=0$ or $c=-a$ if $c=0$ $y=0$ or $x=0$

it is same at  $a=-c$ situation so it does not have zero diveder

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this basically shows that $\mathbb{Z}[ \sqrt{3} ]$ is a ring without any zero dividers if I understood it correctly.